# How can I get the same result as java function getBytes() use PHP?

Tags: java, php

My Java code is like this:

```
public void trans() {
    try {
        byte[] test = "测试".getBytes("utf-8");
        for(byte b:test){
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this prints:

```
-26
-75
-117
-24
-81
-107
```

Now I want to get the same result using PHP, my code is like this:

```
function getUnicodeFromOneUTF8($word) {
$arr = str_split($word);
foreach ($arr as $value)
    echo hexdec(ord($value)). '</br>';
}
getUnicodeFromOneUTF8('测试');
```

But it prints this:

```
230
181
139
232
175
149
```

How can I get the same result?

Comment: Just remove hexdec...

Comment: I just modified the question, it causes a problem with Chinese...

Comment: They are the same bytes, you display them differently (signed vs. unsigned).

Comment: yes, they are the same when I print it with binary in Java, thanks. @Maerlyn

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you might want to use this function for that

```
$result = mb_encode_numericentity('测试test', [0, 0x10FFFF, 0, 0x10FFFF], 'UTF-8');
echo htmlentities($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php